# traverse only specific python directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that traverses all directories to concatenate a variable called classpath. The files that end in `.jar` and `.properties` are being added to the classpath variable..

But this is too generic. I want this to only traverse through directories that are named "lib" or "properties".

I know I need to stick in here something along the lines of:

```
if os.path.basename(root) in ('lib', 'properties'):
```

But dont know enough about python nor os.walk to understand where this goes. Please advice. Thank you in advance!

I am using python 2.4

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import glob

java_command = "/myapps/java/home/bin/java -classpath "

def run(project_dir, main_class, specific_args):
    classpath = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(project_dir):
        has_properties = False
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.jar'):
                classpath.append(os.path.join(root, f))
            if f.endswith('.properties'):
                has_properties = True
        if has_properties:
            classpath.append(root)

    classpath_augment = ':'.join(classpath)

    print java_command, classpath_augment, main_class, specific_args
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick it at the top of the loop:

```
def run(project_dir, main_class, specific_args):
    classpath = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(project_dir):
        if os.path.basename(root) not in ('lib', 'properties'):
            continue

        has_properties = False
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.jar'):
                classpath.append(os.path.join(root, f))
            if f.endswith('.properties'):
                has_properties = True
        if has_properties:
            classpath.append(root)

    classpath_augment = ':'.join(classpath)

    print java_command, classpath_augment, main_class, specific_args
```

Now it'll *skip* any directory that is not named `lib` or `properties`.